# Grid sizing problem

Tags: grid-layouts, rasterize

How is this possible that when I rasterize `Grid` with parameter `ImageSize` set to certain value that the grid changes its proportions?
How to specify exactly the row size of grid and the column size of the grid?

I want the width of columns be the same as the width of rows.

```
Grid[Partition[Range[9], 3], Frame -> All]
Rasterize[%, ImageSize -> 900]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't use `ImageSize`, use `RasterSize -> {900, 900}`. The `ImageSize` will not affect the result of `ImageDimensions` (in the way you intend)

Comment: It will! It depends on the scenario. Try `Grid[Partition[Range[10, 25], 4], Frame -> All]
Rasterize[%, RasterSize -> {900, 900}]`

Comment: Yes of course, I was being imprecise, but `RasterSize` will give you an image rasterized at 900x900. Your code with `ImageSize` gave me an image with dimensions 54x59.

Comment: @flinty: You have no control of the size of `Grid` whatsoever in Mathematica. You can not produce such a simple thing like a grid like a chessboard and in each square some text.

Comment: @flinty: I do not care about dimensions of raster I care about dimension of the grid inside raster.

Comment: @flinty yes but you need to ensure the result is square. Anyway aside from that, you do have some control. Have you tried changing the `ItemSize`, `Spacings`, and `Alignment` options of `Grid`?

Comment: @flinty: By the way, not `ImageSize->{900,900}` nor `RasterSize->{900,900}` gave me image of dimensions 900x900 but `different numberx900`

Comment: @flinty: All this parameters change the image size but you do not know how..i.e. what exact size will be of the rows and columns. It is quite random.

Comment: @flinty in MS Word you have grid and you can set exact width of row and exact width of column. Such a simple thing impossible in Mathematica, only way is to avoid using `Grid` and produce your own code.

Comment: Yes it's quite frustrating. The sizes appear to factor in the text size and dpi. Maybe avoiding grid and using `ImageAssemble` would work better for you? e.g `With[{d = 100, bw = 1}, 
 ImagePad[ImageAssemble[
   Map[ImagePad[Rasterize[#, RasterSize -> {d, d}], bw] &, 
    Partition[Range[9], 3], {2}]], bw]]`